# Easiest way to implement a game menu in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

At the moment my game simply consists of a play button which, when clicked, runs the game; all of this happens in the document class as follows:

```
stage.addChild(playBtn);
playBtn.x = 0;
playBtn.y = stage.stageHeight/2;;
playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playGame);
```

The playGame() function then removes playBtn from the stage and the event listener, and runs the game code. This has been fine for me up until now, but now I want to implement a more complex menu system, which will probably consist of many buttons, graphics, etc (basically a stage select screen). My question is, what would be a more efficient way of displaying a menu on the screen, removing it when a stage is selected and then being able to return to the menu when the game is over? Obviously I'm trying to do all of this without the use of the timeline.

Comment: This is a very broad question but in general, you shouldn't have _anything_ on your timeline. It's much easier to use FlashDevelop to make games and applications for the Flash Player - you can import images, animations and sounds but you work in a real IDE. Flash is a massive hindrance and the use of the timeline makes things far more complicated. Use Flash to create non-interactive animations/images and use FlashDevelop to load the artwork into the game.

Comment: Indeed, this is too broad.  You could have 20 good but completely different answers to this question, and none of them would be that concise.  Consider trying something first, then updating your question to be more specific.  You'll likely want to implement some kind of state management.  Create a separate class for each state instead of having everything in your document class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate classes for each screen. For example a `MainMenu` screen class and a `Game` class. Then your document class becomes a simple screen switching controller, which instantiates, adds and removes screen classes.

As long as each screen only adds content into itself, and not to the stage, the document class need not know or care what's inside the screens, and removing a screen will not require each element in the screen to be removed.

As for how to add all elements to each screen, let the screen class handle it, or a symbol linked to the screen class with all your content.